# What are non-word boundary in regex (\B), compared to word-boundary?

Tags: javascript, regex, word-boundary, boundary, word-boundaries

What are non-word boundary in regex (\B), compared to word-boundary?

Answer (score 105, accepted):

A word boundary (`\b`) is a zero width match that can match:

- Between a word character (`\w`) and a non-word character (`\W`) or
- Between a word character and the start or end of the string.

In Javascript the definition of `\w` is `[A-Za-z0-9_]` and `\W` is anything else.

The negated version of `\b`, written `\B`, is a zero width match where the above does *not* hold. Therefore it can match:

- Between two word characters.
- Between two non-word characters.
- Between a non-word character and the start or end of the string.
- The empty string.

For example if the string is `"Hello, world!"` then `\b` matches in the following places:

```
 H e l l o ,   w o r l d !
^         ^   ^         ^
```

And `\B` matches those places where `\b` doesn't match:

```
 H e l l o ,   w o r l d !
  ^ ^ ^ ^   ^   ^ ^ ^ ^   ^
```

Comment: Nice one.  In my experience, *explaining* word boundaries is considerably more difficult than *using* them.

Comment: I have not seen such a lucid explanation of word boundaries before. Great one!

Comment: For the `\B` example, the label between `start of string` and `H` is missing. Nice explanation otherwise.

Answer (score 4):

The basic purpose of `non-word-boundary` is to created a regex that says:

- if we are at the beginning/end of a `word char` (`\w` = `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`) make sure the previous/next character is also a `word char`,

  e.g.: `"a\B."` ~ `"a\w"`:

  `"ab"`, `"a4"`, `"a_"`, ... but not `"a "`, `"a."`
- if we are at the beginning/end of a `non-word char` (`\W` = `[^a-zA-Z0-9_]`) make sure the previous/next character is also a `non-word char`,

  e.g.: `"-\B."` ~ `"-\W"`:

  `"-."`, `"- "`, `"--"`, ... but not `"-a"`, `"-1"`

For `word-boundary` it's similar but instead of making sure that the adjacent characters are of the same class (`word char`/`non-word car`) they need to differ, hence the name `word's boundary`.