# Notations in Regular Expressions

Tags: regex, notation

I am trying to learn Regular Expressions. I've looked at several tutorials but I did not find them
clear or comprehensive. My questions is when is ^$ used and when is "\b ." used? I know what they
mean but just are sure how.

Some examples:

```
1. \((\d+)\)\.\((\d+)\)\.\((\d+)\)
2. \b1?264[)- ]*\d{3}[- ]*\d{4}\b
3. ^[a-g]{4}$
```

Don't all Regular Expressions have to start with "^" and end with "$" ?

Comment: Read [Mastering Regular Expressions 3rd Edition](http://www.amazon.com/Mastering-Regular-Expressions-Jeffrey-Friedl/dp/0596528124 "Best regex book ever"). Hands down the most useful book I've ever read. The time spent studying this quickly pays for itself many times over.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Before seeing when they are used, first you need to know what they mean:

- `^` is a start of line [anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html).
- `$` is an end-of-line of line anchor.
- `\b` matches a [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html). In other words, it matches between a word character `\w` and either a non-word character `\W` or the start or end of the string.

For example:

- To check if a string *starts* with a digit use `^\d`.
- To check if a string *ends* with a digit use `\d$`.
- To check if a string contains the word `foo` use `\bfoo\b`. Omitting the word boundaries would cause it to match words that contain `foo` such as `seafood`.

Comment: What do you mean "\b" matches between a word character \w and a non-word character \W ?

Comment: @GTyler: I have another answer where I explain \b and \B in more details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4541573/what-are-non-word-boundary-in-regex-b-compared-to-word-boundary  Does that help?

Comment: @Mark Byers: It's more correct to say that `\b` matches between a word character `\w` and not a word character because it can match at the start or end of a string if the first/last character is a word character.