# Regex to capitalize a word

Tags: regex

I have been solving regex problems from different sources. Can you guys help me to figure how the regex for this problem

`Use substitution to replace every occurrence of the word i with the word I (uppercase, I as in me). E.g.: i'm replacing it. am i not? -> I'm replacing it. am I not?. A regex match is replaced with the text in the sub field when using substitution.`

I tried with this regex

```
.*\bi|.*i$
```

But there is this error  `You are not replacing i at the end of the string.`. BTW [regex101](http://regex101.com/quiz/#) is a great site to practice regex problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex should be.....

```
\bi\b
```

with `g` flag

`\b` is a [word boundary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4541573/what-are-non-word-boundary-in-regex-b-compared-to-word-boundary) that helps match individual words.

`g` flag would match all such occurances instead of matching once.