# Regex: exception to negative character class

Tags: python, regex

Using Python with Matthew Barnett's regex module.

I have this string:

```
The well known *H*rry P*tter*.
```

I'm using this regex to process the asterisks to obtain `<em>H*rry P*tter</em>`:

```
REG = re.compile(r"""
(?<!\p{L}|\p{N}|\\)
\*
([^\*]*?) # I need this part to deal with nested patterns; I really can't omit it
\*
(?!\p{L}|\p{N})
""", re.VERBOSE)
```

#### PROBLEM

The problem is that this regex doesn't match this kind of strings unless I protect intraword asterisks first (I convert them to decimal entities), which is awfully expensive in documents with lots of asterisks.

#### QUESTION

Is it possible to tell the negative class to block at internal asterisks **only if** they are not surrounded by word characters?

I tried these patterns in vain:

- `([^(?:[^\p{L}|\p{N}]\*[^\p{L}|\p{N}])]*?)`
- `([^(?<!\p{L}\p{N})\*(?!\p{L}\p{N})]*?)`

Comment: Can you please share the replacing code itself? Also, maybe you want `re.sub(r'\B\*\b([^*]*(?:\b\*\b[^*]*)*)\b\*\B', r'<em>\1</em>', s)`? (If it is Python 2.x, add `u` prefix to enforce a `re.UNICODE` flag).

Comment: Do you mean [**`\B(\*)([^*]*(?:\*\b[^*]*)*)(\*)\B`**](https://regex101.com/r/HKmWDg/1)?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it's just a re.sub like yours, repeated twice to match one level of nesting. I'll try your suggestion now

Comment: Please what do you mean by *nested patterns* here?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it's perfect! thank'you very much. If you do it as an answer I'll accept it

Comment: @revo your regex doesn't work (I get this: `Hey <em>*</em>!` with a string like `'Hey *Har*ry P*tter*!'`). Nested patterns are something like `*Harry *wizard* Potter*`, but they are not a problem, I already solved it by repeating the sub twice

Comment: @revo your regex works, I didn't notice it required capture group 2 instead of 1

Comment: Well if you found your answer there is no more discussion left. My proposed RegEx works if replacement string is `<em>\2</em>`. The one I suggested is the same as @WiktorStribiżew , but since he is a *fast editor guy* I didn't see his edit before posting my comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest a single regex replacement for the cases like you mentioned above:

```
re.sub(r'\B\*\b([^*]*(?:\b\*\b[^*]*)*)\b\*\B', r'<em>\1</em>', s)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SLEeCB/1)

**Details**:

- `\B\*\b` - a `*` that is preceded with a non-word boundary and followed with a word boundary
- `([^*]*(?:\b\*\b[^*]*)*)` - Group 1 capturing:

  - `[^*]*` - 0+ chars other than `*`
  - `(?:\b\*\b[^*]*)*` - zero or more sequences of:

    - `\b\*\b` - a `*` enclosed with word boundaries
    - `[^*]*` - 0+ chars other than `*`
- `\b\*\B` - a `*` that is followed with a non-word boundary and preceded with a word boundary

More information on word boundaries and non-word boundaries:

- [*Word boundaries* at regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)
- [*Difference between `\b` and `\B` in regex*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6664151/difference-between-b-and-b-in-regex)
- [*What are non-word boundary in regex (`\B`), compared to word-boundary?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4541573/what-are-non-word-boundary-in-regex-b-compared-to-word-boundary)