# Formula to split words by uppercase

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I would like to come up with a script to program a custom formula for google sheet. The idea is to split a string composed of multiple words. The formula should recognize the words where there is a capital letter and separate them. The result would be a string where the words are separated by ",".

To clarify this is an example of the string:

```
Nursing StudentStudentNurseNursing School

Desired Result:
Nursing Student,Student,Nurse,Nursing School
```

I have tried to use a formula in Google Sheet:

```
=split(regexreplace(A1,"[A-Z][^A-Z]*","$0"&char(9)),char(9))
```

However, it generates 6 cells with the below strings:

```
Nursing Student Student Nurse Nursing School
```

Can anybody help me or give me some hint?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265834

Comment: Stefano, please check our two answers below and please consider upvoting and accepting the answer that works best for you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
=REGEXREPLACE(A1,"(\B)([A-Z])",",$2")
```

- `\B` not a word `B`order.
- `[A-Z]` Upper case letter.
- If `\B` is followed by a upper case letter, replace the `\B` with `,`

Comment: I doubt there is any point in capturing groups here, `=REGEXREPLACE(A1,"\B[A-Z]",",$0")` will do.

Answer (score 3):

If you plan to insert a comma in between a lowercase letter and an uppercase letter, you may use either of:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(A1,"([a-z])([A-Z])","$1,$2")
=REGEXREPLACE(A1,"([[:lower:]])([[:upper:]])","$1,$2")
```

where

- `([a-z])` / `([[:lower:]])` - Capturing group 1 (later referred to with `$1` from the replacement pattern): any lowercase ASCII letter
- `([A-Z])` / `([[:upper:]])` - Capturing group 2 (later referred to with `$2` from the replacement pattern): any uppercase ASCII letter

[image]

Note that [another suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51446584/3832970), based on a [non-word boundary `\B`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4541573/what-are-non-word-boundary-in-regex-b-compared-to-word-boundary), that can be written as `=REGEXREPLACE(A1,"\B[A-Z]",",$0")`, will also match an uppercase letter after `_` and any digit, so it might overfire if you do not expect that behavior.