# Regex search only works for half my file, even though all entries are the same format

Tags: python, regex

I'm having some difficulty with my regex search, and I don't quite know why. I have a file with values formatted as such:

```
         1  -1   2 SER HA   H   4.477 0.003 1
         2  -1   2 SER HB2  H   3.765 0.001 1
         3  -1   2 SER HB3  H   3.765 0.001 1
         4  -1   2 SER C    C 173.726 0.2   1
         5  -1   2 SER CA   C  58.16  0.047 1
         6  -1   2 SER CB   C  64.056 0.046 1
         7   0   3 HIS H    H   8.357 0.004 1
         8   0   3 HIS HA   H   4.725 0.003 1
         9   0   3 HIS HB2  H   3.203 0.003 2
        .....
         63   7  10 GLU HA   H   4.328 0.004 1
         64   7  10 GLU HB2  H   2.154 0.005 2
         65   7  10 GLU HB3  H   2.156 0.004 2
         66   7  10 GLU HG2  H   2.262 0.014 2
         67   7  10 GLU HG3  H   2.464 0.001 2
         68   7  10 GLU C    C 177.242 0.2   1
         69   7  10 GLU CA   C  59.009 0.068 1
...
```

I want to search for the above strings exclusively line by line.

```
import re
with open('delete.txt') as file:
  for lines in file:
    modifier=lines.strip()
    A=re.search('\B\d+\s[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]\s[A-Z]',modifier)
    if A != None:
        search=A.string
        print(search)
```

The formatting for the above files changes a lot, however what is always consistent is there will be a number, followed by 3 letters, followed by another letter. I.E. `2 SER HA`

So I decided to use that as my regex search, but this isn't quite working. After the `63 7 10 GLU` line it works perfectly, but it doesn't find any of the other entries before that, despite the fact it appears every line is the same format.

The above example is a MVE.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you do not need to start searching at a non-word boundary position. You may add `\b` though. Also, you may print the `lines` variable without getting it from the match data object if there is a match.

Use

```
import re
with open('delete.txt', 'r') as file:
  for lines in file:
    modifier=lines.strip()                              # Remove leading/trailing whitespace
    if re.search(r'\b\d+\s+[A-Z]{3}\s+[A-Z]',modifier): # If there is a match
        print(modifier)                                 # Print it
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/IOIqPM/5).

If you need to get the field value, replace the last `[A-Z]` with `[A-Z0-9]+`, see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/IOIqPM/4).

**Regex details**

- `\b` - word boundary
- `\d+` - 1+ digits
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `[A-Z]{3}` - three uppercase ASCII letters
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `[A-Z]` - an uppercase ASCII letter.

Note the use of a raw string literal, `r'...'` so that we do not have to double escape backslashes that denote regex escapes.

Comment: I thought \b is for characters at the start and end of the string, like ^. (i.E. for the above lines it would be 1 1 for the first line, 69 1 for the last). It's why I used \B, because the characters I'm looking for are in the middle of the string, not at the starts or end.

Comment: @samman See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4541573/what-are-non-word-boundary-in-regex-b-compared-to-word-boundary). `\B\d` matches a digit that is immediately preceded with a word char (a letter, digit or `_`), it won't match a digit after a non-word char and at the start of string.

Comment: Oh I see, I thought that only related the entire string, not the individual words within the string as well. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
fhand=open('delete.txt')
for line in fhand:
    inp=line.rstrip()
    x=re.findall('^\d\s\S\d\s(\d\s\S+\s\S+)',inp) 
    if len(x) >0:  
        print(x)
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained how the code you provided answers the question.