# Regex to remove leading zero except for first

Tags: python, regex

I have the following cases where I'd like to remove the leading zeros

```
0 -> 0
0.1 -> 0.1
-0.1 -> -0.1
00.01 -> 0.01
001 -> 1
```

So whenever there are multiple zeros before the decimal or number, then we remove them. If the zero is by itself, we keep it. I have the following regex:

```
r'^[0]*'
```

but this removes all leading zeros. How can I fix this so that it does what I want it to do?

Comment: You could apply the regex, then after if the string has length 0 or if the first char is a `.` then you can append a 0 to the start of the string.

Comment: Also, `re.sub(r'^0+(?![.\s])', '', text)` might work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`Decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#decimal.Decimal) class to convert the string to a number and back:

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> str(Decimal("0.01"))
'0.01'
>>> str(Decimal("000.01"))
'0.01'
>>> str(Decimal("-00.01"))
'-0.01'
>>> str(Decimal("1"))
'1'
```

Answer (score 1):

try this regex:

```
>>> import re
>>> text = '0\n0.1\n-0.1\n00.01\n001'
>>> print(re.sub(r'0+(\d+)(\.\d+)?', r'\1\2', text))
0
0.1
-0.1
0.01
1
```

Answer (score 1):

An idea with `\B` which matches a [non word boundary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4541573/what-are-non-word-boundary-in-regex-b-compared-to-word-boundary).

```
^0+\B
```

[See demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/imZRi7/1)