# Javascript ignore regex if at the end

Tags: javascript, regex, string, input, replace

I'm trying to format some strings with delimiters using regex, and its almost done, but my delimiter continues to appear at end of string.

For example, I have this code:

```
var myString = "abcdefghi"
var result = myString.replace(/(.{1,3})(?:(?=.{3})\.(.{1,3})(?:(?=.{3}))?)?/g, '$1.');
console.log(result) // abc.def.ghi.
```

And I am expecting `abc.def.ghi`

Comment: You can also try [`s.replace(/.{3}\B/g, '$&.')`](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/j/Pye1RKFYwVZBKTEpOSU1LT0jU8maCyRYlAoSLtYrSi3ISUxO1dDXqzaujXHST9dRUFdR01PXtOZKzs8rzs9J1cvJT9cAKtf8/x8A). This works with `\B` which represents a [*non word boundary*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4541573/what-are-non-word-boundary-in-regex-b-compared-to-word-boundary) ([regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/CIgj6m/1)).

Comment: What should it be for `abcdefghij` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this approach

```js
var myString = "abcdefghi";
var result = myString.match(/.{1,3}/g).join(".");
console.log(result)
```